# Suggestions with GroceryList

Tags: java, class, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am making a program where I have a class called GroceryItem, Another called GroceryList, and the third is main method which will run the program.

I have done alot in this program, but I am stuck now. Please have a look on my code and help me.

GroceryItem Class:

```
public class GroceryItem {



    private String name;  
    private double pricePerUnit;  
    private int quantity;  

    public GroceryItem(int quantity, String name, double pricePerUnit) {  

        this.name = name;  
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;  
        this.quantity = quantity;  

    }  

    public double getCost() {  

        return (this.quantity * this.pricePerUnit);  
    }  

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {  

        this.quantity = quantity;  

    }  

}
```

---

GroceryList Class:

```
public class GroceryList {



    private GroceryItem[] list = null;  
    int num;  

    public GroceryList() {  

        list = new GroceryItem[10];  
        this.num = 0;  

    }  

    // Constructs a new empty grocery list.  
    public void add(GroceryItem item) {  
        list.add(item);  

    }  

    // Adds the given item order to this list, if the list is not full (has  
    // fewer than 10 items).  
    public double getTotalCost() {  
        double totalcost = 0;  
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){  
        totalcost += getGroceryItemOrder(getCost());  
        }  

        return totalcost;  
    }  
    // Returns the total sum cost of all grocery item orders in this list.  
}
```

---

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    GroceryList list = new GroceryList();  
    GroceryItem carrots = new GroceryItem(5,"Carrots", 0.40);  
    list.add(carrots);  
    GroceryItem apples = new GroceryItem( 4,"Apples", 0.15);  
    list.add(apples);  
    GroceryItem rice = new GroceryItem( 1,"Rice", 1.10);  
    list.add(rice);  
    GroceryItem tortillas = new GroceryItem(10,"Tortillas", .05);  
    list.add(tortillas);  
    GroceryItem strawberries = new GroceryItem(1,"Strawberries", 4.99);  
    list.add(strawberries);  
    GroceryItem chicken = new GroceryItem( 1,"Chicken", 5.99);  
    list.add(chicken);  
    GroceryItem lettuce = new GroceryItem( 1,"Lettuce", 0.99);  
    list.add(lettuce);  
    GroceryItem milk = new GroceryItem( 2,"Milk", 2.39);  
    list.add(milk);  
    GroceryItem yogurt = new GroceryItem( 3,"Yogurt", 0.60);  
    list.add(yogurt);  
    GroceryItem chocolate = new GroceryItem(1,"Chocolate", 3.99);  
    list.add(chocolate);  

}
```

}

Comment: You haven't stated a question/problem. (Unless I missed it.)

Comment: The problem for is that I am stuck and cannot get it to work...

Comment: Replace  private GroceryItem[] list = null;  by List you are getting error at list.add()

Comment: Hi!I am really new to this stuff. I have been stuck here for many hours now and cannot find out why the whole program is not working... The functionality of this program is that the GroceryItem and GroceryList program will work together and the MAIN will run the whole system. Please help!

Comment: You have a few answers now. Do they help you? If not, please point out what is going wrong. Tell us what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead. If you have an error message, read it carefully and try to understand what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to add your Grocery element.

**GroceryList class**

```
public class GroceryList {



List<GroceryItem> list = null;  
int num;  

public GroceryList() {  

    list = new ArrayList<GroceryItem>();  
    this.num = 0;  

}  

// Constructs a new empty grocery list.  

   public void add(GroceryItem item) {  
    list.add(item);  
   System.out.println("Added Grocery :::: >>>> NAME:" +item.getName()+ " :::::  PRICE PER UNIT: "+item.getPricePerUnit()+" :::::: QUANTITY: "+item.getQuantity()+" ::::: FINALCOST: "+(item.getQuantity()*item.getPricePerUnit()) );}


// Adds the given item order to this list, if the list is not full (has  
// fewer than 10 items).  
 public double getTotalCost() {  
    double totalcost = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){  
    totalcost += list.get(i).getCost();  
    }  

    return totalcost;  
}  
// Returns the total sum cost of all grocery item orders in this list.  
}  


    /// Add this function as toString class

    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "GroceryList [list=" + list + ", num=" + num + "]";
        }
```

---

```
// add a function for finding cost per item like this

public HashMap<String,Double>  getCostPerItem(int i) {
           HashMap<String, Double> itemPriceName= new HashMap<String, Double>();
           itemPriceName.put(list.get(i).getName(), 
              (list.get(i).getPricePerUnit()*list.get(i).getQuantity()));
          return itemPriceName;
       }
```

---

// IN main function you can call above specified function

```
for(int i=0;i<list.list.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Cost Per Item  "+list.getCostPerItem(i));
        }
```

---

Comment: Thanks for help my friend, but I am sorry I cannot figure out where to add that... Please help me more than that...

Comment: I updated the code, no ERRORS now, but the program is still not running...No response..

Comment: There is no print statement in your `main` function. If you add that, you should probably get the right result by now.

Comment: What should I print out?

Comment: Well what do you want it to print out? I assume you want to print the total cost that is calculated by the method `getTotalCost()`. So add a line printing that. (And after that, to verify that it works correctly, experiment with putting different values in your shopping list, and see if you get the right results).

Comment: Well if you see me main method, you can that I have products in my GroceryList and that is what I want to print out...But cant figure out how to..

Comment: Check updated code above and add this as a last line your main function --- `System.out.printf("%.2f",list.getTotalCost());`

Comment: Well Vinayak it is working not, but the only thing I get out is the totalcost, i want to get out this: quantity name price of all products and then the totalcost in the end. Can you please help...

Comment: I think this is what you want check updated answer. PLease

Comment: Add this to your main function last line `System.out.printf("Total Cost of Groceries :::: >>>> %.2f",list.getTotalCost());`

Comment: Now, I get some error with your new code...

Comment: And when we are talking about getCost, then I want to get the totalCost of per item, i mean: quantity*price per unit. Totalcost per item. Please help help help

Comment: Sorry my mistake . Accidentally copied data. Please check now.

Comment: Hi! Really really thanks for your help. I just wanted to know, if I could get the result with toString? Please help with that aswell.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanku so much for your help!

Comment: `System.out.printf("Total Cost of Groceries :::: >>>> %.2f",list.getTotalCost());` check updated code for toString() and use the code given for toString()

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the method `add` to add things to an array. 
You should either use an `ArrayList` or similar data structure, or add items using an index:

```
list[ index++ ] = item
```

The reason is that simple arrays don't have an `add` method. `ArrayList`, and several other collection classes, do.

Also, in your original code, you have the line:

```
totalcost += getGroceryItemOrder(getCost());
```

There is no method `getGroceryItemOrder(...)` defined in this code. And, in this form, it will call `getCost()` on the `GroceryItemList` class. `GroceryItemList` has no such method, so you get an error.
You want to call `getCost()` on the current list item, so the line you need is:

```
totalcost += list[i].getCost();
```

Comment: I get an error while doing that: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<GroceryItem>"

Comment: That's because you now use a `List<GroceryItem>` instead of an array, as in the original code. So take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of the List class; what you need is the method `get(...)`. You need to call this on your `list` instance.